# Python Bot-Framework Proactive message

Tags: python, azure, botframework

Issue: Whenever there is an code update we make the deployment to Azure using az command line. After the deployment is done, users who have previously conversated with the bot stop receiving the proactive messages. Once they send a new message to bot post deployment, then only they are able to receive the proactive messages.

How to make sure that the users keep on receiving the proactive messages, even after the code for the bot has been updated?

```
async def _send_proactive_message(txt):
    for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.values():
        AppCredentials.trust_service_url(conversation_reference.service_url)
        await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(conversation_reference, lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity(txt), APP_ID,)
```

The above code is used to send the message

Comment: after deployment your connection is lost right ( client to server) ?

Comment: No, user are still able to query

Comment: Like is there another way to update the bot code? Without doing a zip deployment

Comment: What channel are you using, and how are you storing your conversation references? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am using MS Teams, I am explicitly not storing conversation references anywhere. Do I need to save them somewhere?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal - Yes you do. If you're not storing your conversation references anywhere, how does the `_send_proactive_message` function get them?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal - Are you still working on this?

Comment: It got fixed, I started to dump and load the conversation_references from blob storage, that fixed the issue